# Can we define unitary representations on semigroups

Tags: representation-theory, semigroups

A representation on a semigroup $S$ is a pair $(\pi,H_\pi)$ where $\pi$ is a homomorphism from $S$ into $B(H_\pi)$ and $H_\pi$ is a Hilbert space.

In the group case, a representation $\pi$ of a group $G$ is said to be unitary if $\pi(g)$ is a unitary operator for all $g\in G$.

Can I use the same definition for a semigroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to make the definition as you see fit. A unitary representation of a semigroup would have the same meaning as a unitary representation of a group.

Comment: Lets say that we have $a,b,c\in S$ and $ab=ac$ but $b\ne c$. Then $\pi(ab) = \pi(ac)$ and since $\pi(a)$ is invertible we will get $\pi(b)=\pi(c)$ I can't see how this will make a problem. you cant conclude that $b=c$ since $\pi$ it self is not invertible. did I get what you tried to say?

Comment: @user100478 Good point. And you could always send everything to the identity. I've edited my answer.